# Ghostscript to run in PHP shell_exec gs: command not found

Tags: php, exec, ghostscript, shell-exec

I have installed ghost script locally and it runs fine from terminal with a command like:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

But if I run the same command from exec() or shell_exec() the command fails. I managed to get an out put which highlights the following error:

> gs: command not found

I am running MAMP locally with PHP 7.1.6 and Apache.

SOLUTION:

```
/usr/local/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: you may need to provide the full gs path

Comment: You were right!